# unix shell script : Merging data(lines) of 2 different text files

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk

files have many entries but for sample posting only 2 entries each. I want to merge file1 first line content with file 2's 1st line content and so on.example is as below.

**file1.txt**

```
Start Date: 2019-01-08 04:14:59; End Date: 2019-01-08 04:15:50; Difference in seconds = 51
Start Date: 2019-01-08 04:16:57; End Date: 2019-01-08 04:17:02; Difference in seconds = 5
```

**file2.txt**

```
Fnb_dm__exachange_rollback_character
dnb_exchange_brm_rollback_character
```

I want output like below:

```
Fnb_dm__exachange_rollback_character :Start Date: 2019-01-08 04:14:59; End Date: 2019-01-08 04:15:50; Difference in seconds = 51
dnb_exchange_brm_rollback_character :Start Date: 2019-01-08 04:16:57; End Date: 2019-01-08 04:17:02; Difference in seconds = 5
```

How to do it using ksh?

Comment: Do you specifically need the delimiter to be the two-character string ` :` (space-colon)? if not you could use something as simple as `paste -d: file2.txt file1.txt`

Comment: @stelldriver : no specific requirement about delimiter

Comment: @Pankaj -- no no no; open a *new* question -- don't move the goalposts on this one!

Comment: @JeffSchaller:will do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `paste` command - for example, to merge the files line-by-line with a colon delimiter:

```
$ paste -d: file2.txt file1.txt
Fnb_dm__exachange_rollback_character:Start Date: 2019-01-08 04:14:59; End Date: 2019-01-08 04:15:50; Difference in seconds = 51
dnb_exchange_brm_rollback_character:Start Date: 2019-01-08 04:16:57; End Date: 2019-01-08 04:17:02; Difference in seconds = 5
```

If you need a multi-character delimiter, then that is possible using `pr` ex.

```
$ pr -TmJS' :' file2.txt file1.txt
Fnb_dm__exachange_rollback_character :Start Date: 2019-01-08 04:14:59; End Date: 2019-01-08 04:15:50; Difference in seconds = 51
dnb_exchange_brm_rollback_character :Start Date: 2019-01-08 04:16:57; End Date: 2019-01-08 04:17:02; Difference in seconds = 5
```

Comment: it worked ,thanks a lot,Actully I want this file to be sorted on last field  I,e  example (51), actually I knw how to sort but for that I have to awk that colum then only I can sort (which will give me only last filed in result)but I want to keep all data on that line also, so how can I achive this?

Comment: sorting wasn't one of this question's requirements; I'd suggest that you open a new question with steeldriver's current solution and your further requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I have done by below method and it worked fine

```
i=`awk 'NR==1{print $0}' file1`;awk -v i="$i" 'NR==1{$0=$0i}1' file2
```

output

```
Fnb_dm__exachange_rollback_characterStart Date: 2019-01-08 04:14:59; End Date: 2019-01-08 04:15:50; Difference in seconds = 51
dnb_exchange_brm_rollback_character
```

Comment: shouldn't the `dnb_exchange_brm_rollback_character ` line have more fields next to it?

Answer (score 0):

I have done by below method and it worked fine

```
for i in 1 2; do j=`sed -n ''$i'p' file1`;sed -n ''$i'p' file2|sed "s/.*/&$j/g"; done
```

output

```
Fnb_dm__exachange_rollback_characterStart Date: 2019-01-08 04:14:59; End Date: 2019-01-08 04:15:50; Difference in seconds = 51
dnb_exchange_brm_rollback_characterStart Date: 2019-01-08 04:16:57; End Date: 2019-01-08 04:17:02; Difference in seconds = 5
```

Comment: I suppose you should explain that your solution works only for the stripped-down example; from the OP: `files have many entries but for sample posting only 2 entries each`